# How to acquire frames for live video processing in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, video-processing

I am trying to create an application for both iOS and Android with Xamarin forms, which can process the individual frames of a live video. I am at the beginning of the project and not very advanced in programming in general. Therefore, first of all I want to start by creating a function which runs the camera and extracts the individual frames. I haven't found too much content on this except this live barcode scanner ([Live Barcode Scanner in Xamarin.Forms](https://yushulx.medium.com/how-to-build-camera-barcode-scanner-app-in-xamarin-forms-dfdd95878fa2)), written in Xamarin forms. However, in the code I can't figure out which part is responsible for the acquisitions of the individual frames. Also, the code for in the android solution is very different form the iOS solution and I was wondering why that is.

Then, I found this real time object detector app ([Real Time Object Detector in Xamarin.Android](https://geeks.ms/xamarinteam/2019/07/04/realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-xamarin-android/)), which is written in Xamarin.Android. It seems to be a little bit more understandable to me, how they acquired the individual frames for further object detection. But then again, it would only be a solution for Android then.

Does anyone have any advice, on how this frame extraction can be solved for both platforms, IOS and Android?

Comment: there are numerous existing questions that address this problem for iOS and Android.  Any solution is going to require platform specific code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me what is the role of the shared code then, if iOS and Android each need platform specific code? That's what I don't really understand...

Comment: Shared code is for platform agnostic code - data access, calculations, services, etc - or for things where Xamarin Forms or a nuget package provides a cross-platform API.   For things that are **very** platform specific, like extracting frames from video, you need to write platform specific code.

Comment: The company I work for has created the [LEADTOOLS Xamarin Camera Control](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/xamarin/camera) to simplify using the device’s camera on multiple platforms using the same code. There are sample apps that use this control such as the [Barcode Scanner and QR Code Reader](https://www.leadtools.com/apps/barcode). You can try the control and obtain the source code for sample apps by downloading the SDK’s free evaluation from [this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).

Comment: @AminDodin thanks for your reply. Is there a possibility to see the code of the Barcode Scanner app, so I can get some idea how to implement a frame processing with live capture?

Comment: You can chech dependencyservice to invoke native platform functionality from shared code. here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: @janniscodesnow If you download and setup the Main evaluation installer of LEADTOOLS [from here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads), you can find the source code of several Xamarin projects that use the Camera control in the folder "C:\LEADTOOLS21\Examples\Xamarin\". This includes BarcodeDemo, Business Card Reader Demo (BCReaderDemo) and CameraDemo, among others. If you need help using the Camera control, technical support is free through email and online chat even while using the free evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EMGU library

More specifically the `Emgu.CV.VideoCapture` class.

```cs
var videoCapture = new Emgu.CV.VideoCapture(0);
videoCapture.ImageGrabbed += VideoCapture_ImageGrabbed;
videoCapture.Start();
```

They also have a maui version.
It's available for Windows, Android, iOS, Mac.
For Android and iOS you'll need a paid license to get the required platform nugets.